# vim compiles with wrong python version (and not working with needed version)

Tags: python, macos, vim, compilation

#### In brief:

I have a problem with compiling vim with preferred python version.
When I use `--enable-pythoninterp` it compiles with system OSX python version.
When I use `--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic` I get an error in vim while trying `:py import sys`

#### Here is what I was doing in more detail:

```
% git clone https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim.git
% cd macvim
% ./configure --enable-pythoninterp \
     --with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config <- this option has no affects on result
...
checking for python... /usr/local/bin/python
checking Python version... 2.7
checking Python is 1.4 or better... yep
checking Python's install prefix... /usr/local
checking Python's execution prefix... /usr/local
checking Python's configuration directory... /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config
...
% make
...
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
% open src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app
```

In the opened MacVim I type:

```
:py import sys; print (sys.version, sys.executable)
('2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]',
 '/usr/bin/python')
```

**Why `2.6.1`?

Why `/usr/bin/python`?

My default python is 2.7! And it lives at `/usr/local/bin/python`**
I was searching for solution all day. And I found it. It is [=dynamic](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2011/06/13/how-to-build-macvim-with-python-2-7/) attribute (but this solution had not explanation).

After that I tried to recompile vim with dynamic python:

```
% ./configure --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic
... output the same ...
% make
% open src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app
```

In opened MacVim:

```
:py import sys
```

**And here comes an error:**

```
E370: Could not load library libpython2.7.a
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

---

My OSX version is 10.6.8.
Default python version is 2.7.

```
% which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

**Can anybody explain how python is integrating into vim during the compilation?

And how to fix the error with libpython2.7.a?**

---

**update**: I no longer have the environment described at the question. So I couldn't test new answers. But remaining part of mankind will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10):

My solution was to delete the configure cache file which was created from a previous built where I used the python which came with OSX.

Then I installed a new python version with homebrew and couldn't get .configure to take the new python version, even though I updated my PATH variable and which python showed the right python version.

Deleting the cache file and running configure again solved my problem.

```
rm src/auto/config.cache
./configure --enable-pythoninterp
```

Maybe it helps anybody.

Comment: Actually yes :-) And I am compiling on a Debian machine with a custom python version. I previously compiled with the builtin python and now it keeps linking to that version even if I provided the configure option for the other one. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I compiled *Macvim* from source and tried to use the python version 2.7 from macports in:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

Some modules were not found, for example the os module. The reason for this was that the PYTHONPATH variable **inside** macvim is wrong!

To test, open macvim and type:

```
:python print sys.path
```

I got the following paths (note the ending, which is nonsense):

```
...
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.5/'
...
```

I presume the reason is in the linker flag "-framework Python". This picks up the wrong, i.e. the *system* python framework. If I change the line in the `src/auto/configure` script from:

```
if test "x$MACOSX" = "xyes" && ${vi_cv_path_python} -c \
"import sys; sys.exit(${vi_cv_var_python_version} < 2.3)"; then
      vi_cv_path_python_plibs="-framework Python"
```

to

```
if test "x$MACOSX" = "xyes" && ${vi_cv_path_python} -c \
"import sys; sys.exit(${vi_cv_var_python_version} < 2.3)"; then
      vi_cv_path_python_plibs="-F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks -framework Python"
```

Running configure again, after make clean,
Macvim  compiles and works  as expected. The -F flag tells the linker in which directory to find the following framework. Macports installs the Python.framework in this directory, YMMV.

Comment: Thanx. But not working for me. MacVim is compiles with 2.6 version anyway.

Comment: I ended up adding the "-F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks" to src/auto/confik.mk - which you have to do AFTER you run configure - but it works.

Comment: @Stephen, where exactly did you added the `"-F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks"`?

Comment: @oluckyman I don't remember exactly, and I don't have that computer anymore - but I think there's only one place in that file where it says `"-framwork Python"` and I added right before that.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to modify the configuration file, use config such as(in one line):
vi_cv_path_python="/usr/local/bin/python" PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX="/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks" ./configure --enable-luainterp --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp

Answer (score 5):

I had a the same probleme as you (trying to compile MacVim with Python 2.7) and I finally managed to do it.

First the `dynamic` option **doesn't work** ! I've seen that *tip* too on the net, but if you look at the configure script (or just the help) it's not recognized. Therefore **don't use it**. That's equivalent to disabling python, which explain why :py doesn't work. You haven't compiled MacVim with Python.

What I've done at the end was reinstall Python 2.7.2 using the official installer on the Python [website](http://www.python.org/getit/). 
You should then have a `config`  in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config`.

Try to compile again with the following options

```
% ./configure --enable-pythoninterp \
   --with-python-config-dir=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/python2.7/config
```

That gave me an error at the end of the compilation, but if I ignore it and launch the binary anyway that works. This problem might be specific to my computer (it  seems to be related to the *icon* instalation).
Good luck.

Note that's the way I managed to compile MacVim with Python 2.7 (which was my objective) not necessarily the way to compile it with my runtime version of Python.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the proper "python" is in your $PATH, which might not be the case when using "sudo".

There is an option to set the python binary to be used (if you cannot modify $PATH):

```
export vi_cv_path_python=/usr/local/bin/python
```

But still, with `enable-pythoninterp=dynamic` it failed to load libpython2.7.a when running ":python import sys", saying "E448: Could not load library function _PyArg_Parse_SizeT".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the root of your problem lies in that Python is looking to the wrong directory.  That should be the first part you look to correct, before worrying about integrating into vim.  All Macs come with a version of Python already installed on their machine, in /usr/local/bin/python.  Usually by the time you get the machine, you want install a more recent version of Python.  The new version should be located:

```
% which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I don't know how you installed Python to begin with, but the easiest way is easy_install or pip.  This is a [good link](http://blog.praveengollakota.com/47430655).  If that doesn't solve your path problem, then you should [see here](http://cs.simons-rock.edu/python/pythonpath.html).  Hopefully this is all you need and the problem with vim will be resolved.

Comment: thx for the comment. I have installed python from the source. So, can I now use pip to reinstall python that had been already installed? or should I unistall the existing python first?

Comment: of course it's always cleaner to uninstall and then reinstall.  i would suggest doing it that way - it's not like you have much to lose.  then, if that doesn't solve the problem, you'll need to update the path manually using the second link.

Comment: I had `export PYTHONPATH=<sys.path>` where `<sys.path>` is output of `sys.path` command in python console and recompile macvim, but this not helps. Python2.7 itself works fine and I don't know easy ways to uninstall python2.7 compiled from source. Also I'm afraid to corrupt dependences of my python2.7 with other packages/eggs already installed (I have django projects that are using python2.7). Do I have to reinstall all eggs after reinstalling python?

Comment: Before you go about reinstalling the other eggs or even thinking about it, when you type `which python`, what does it say?  Did you create the environment.plist as suggested, in order to force your machine to see the proper path?

Comment: `which python` says `/usr/local/bin/python`. I did't create the environment.plist instead I exported to PYTHONPATH all paths from output of `sys.path` command (there are paths: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*`, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` and so on. But it didn't helps

Answer (score 0):

I found the above answer to be dangerous-- caused fatal errors when closing buffers in macvim.

The answer found here is much more stable:
[Vim failing to compile with python on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490513/vim-failing-to-compile-with-python-on-os-x/8276426#8276426)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same wish, and [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) fulfilled it without additional fiddling:

```
$ port info macvim
MacVim @7.3.snapshot66, Revision 2 (editors)
Variants:             big, cscope, [+]huge, perl, python, python25, python26, python27, python31, python32, python33, ruby, ruby19, tcl, universal, xim
...

$ sudo port install macvim +python27
--->  Computing dependencies for MacVim
--->  Fetching archive for MacVim
--->  Attempting to fetch MacVim-7.3.snapshot66_2+huge+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/MacVim
--->  Attempting to fetch MacVim-7.3.snapshot66_2+huge+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/MacVim
--->  Attempting to fetch MacVim-7.3.snapshot66_2+huge+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/MacVim
--->  Fetching distfiles for MacVim
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for MacVim
--->  Extracting MacVim
--->  Applying patches to MacVim
--->  Configuring MacVim
--->  Building MacVim
--->  Staging MacVim into destroot
--->  Installing MacVim @7.3.snapshot66_2+huge+python27
--->  Deactivating MacVim @7.3.snapshot66_2+huge
--->  Cleaning MacVim
--->  Activating MacVim @7.3.snapshot66_2+huge+python27
--->  Cleaning MacVim
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

Note: As you can see above (`deactivating`), I've tried the default (precompiled) MacVim first (ie. `sudo port install macvim` -> `MacVim @7.3.snapshot66_2+huge`), and it didn't have Python support compiled in.

After the adding the `+python27` variant, running `:py import sys; print (sys.version, sys.executable)` inside the newly installed MacVim now returns:

```
('2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:28) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]', '/Applications/MacPorts/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim')
```

which happens to be the same as I have in my shell (depending on your `$PATH` and `port select python`):

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:28)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
...
```

Comment: This return me an error I don't know why...--->  Building MacVim
Error: org.macports.build for port MacVim returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port MacVim for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_editors_MacVim/MacVim/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port macvim failed

Answer (score 0):

The fix I found for this issue involved deleting the source and reacquiring it. I'm sure hg has a way to just delete the local changes, but I couldn't really find it in the help file.
I didn't use MacVim, but I suspect your issue is for the same reason.

Looking through the output of the configuration script it appears that it caches the python installation it used previously and just uses that.