# homebrew macvim with python2.7.3 support not working

Tags: python, vim, macvim, homebrew

I installed macvim with homebrew, with python support. My incantation was as follow:

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

Now when I open a python file, I get a series of errors if I try to import anything. e.g. if I `import re` I see `ImportError: no module name re`.

The first time I open macvim after installing, I get `'import site' failed; use -v for traceback` in the terminal where I opened macvim. This is after running my first python command.

What does this mean and and how do I fix it?

Comment: I should note I'm trying to use brew python for easy management of extras like qt and PyQt. I know that simply using the system wide python would be a fix, but not the fix I'm looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got this working with a quick hack where you temporarily point the system python to your preferred python:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
sudo mv Current Current-sys
sudo mv 2.7 2.7-sys
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 Current
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 2.7

brew rm macvim # optionall, only if you had it installed previously  
brew install macvim --override-system-vim

sudo mv Current-sys Current
sudo mv 2.7-sys 2.7
```

Comment: Tried a number of other options, none of them worked, but this did!  Thanks so much :)

Comment: Nice and easy hack. It could be noted that Homebrew's copy of Python should be installed first. Python version may vary.

Comment: Does this need to be *temporary* or can’t the “system” framework version simply always be symlinked to Homebrew’s? What problems could be expected by that approach?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I honestly couldn't say, but I'd worry that there'd be some system process that expects a certain version of Python and having a different version could cause subtle and hard to diagnose issues. Or if you change package managers in a couple of years and forget to change the symlink it could cost you some time.

Comment: Thank you @Dean, with a small tweak (my edit) it works even in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

my wild guess is that you should add the homebrew install folder to your .bash_profile like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin:$PATH
```

after that write in the shell "source .bash_profile" so it reloads. Also please check the output of

```
which python
```

to make sure you are using homebrew python

Comment: I don't think this quite does it-- if you ask vim: `:python print sys.version` it still prints 2.6.1 regardless of the path...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on the homebrew option and using the answer suggested here:

[vim compiles with wrong python version (and not working with needed version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294554/vim-compiles-with-wrong-python-version-and-not-working-with-needed-version/9566769#9566769)

It's a shame it appears this cant be done via brew. Looks like somebody needs to patch the macvim distribution itself.

Comment: This wasn't quite right either-- caused [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163126/modified-macvim-seeing-fatal-error). I found [this answer to be more stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490513/vim-failing-to-compile-with-python-on-os-x/8276426#8276426)