# MacVim vdebug python error

Tags: python, macos, vim, xdebug

I am trying to use [vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) with MacVim and xdebug to debug code. I have MacVim and python installed via homebrew and xdebug is installed and working fine with MacGDBp.

When I listen in vdebug with the F5 key and reload a page (xdebug remote autostart is on) I get a python error in the vdebug quickfix window:

```
An error occured: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikedfunk/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/start_vdebug.py", line 31, in run
    self.runner.run()
  File "/Users/mikedfunk/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 160, in run
    self.open()
  File "/Users/mikedfunk/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 74, in open
    raise e
ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

I've googled this for a while and can't find a working solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that anything like this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068510/using-simplexmltreebuilder-in-elementtree)?

Comment: I don't know python but I tried adding the code from answer one to runner.py. That threw another error because I don't know python. I made sure I updated all with ```brew update``` and ```brew upgrade```. Same thing. I'm not on CentOS so answer two didn't help. Answer four is more python.

I think the problem is something with my python installation because this project has a test suite and seems to work for others. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python view homebrew, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me! Posted in case anyone else has the same problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697440/557215

It temporarily links the homebrew version of python to the mac system version before reinstalling MacVim. Now xdebug works!