# modified macvim seeing fatal error

Tags: python, macos, vim, macvim

I compiled my macvim installation against python 2.7 by making the modification described here: [vim compiles with wrong python version (and not working with needed version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294554/vim-compiles-with-wrong-python-version-and-not-working-with-needed-version/9566769#9566769)

And now I'm seeing an error any time I close more than one window at a time.

`Vim(42372,0x7fff702a2cc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT`

Anybody have any advice for how to fix this?

Comment: this happens whenever a buffer closes, for whatever reason.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490513/vim-failing-to-compile-with-python-on-os-x/8276426#8276426