# Getting python link error on OSX, PyMac_Error in linker flags

Tags: python, linker-errors, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Whenever I try to install `CMU PocketSphinx` I get the error :

```
checking for Python include path... -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
checking for Python library path... -L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -lpython2.7
checking for Python site-packages path... /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking python extra libraries... -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation 
checking python extra linking flags... -u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
checking consistency of all components of python development environment... no
configure: error: in `/Users/username/Desktop/CMUSPHINX/sphinxbase-5prealpha':
configure: error: 
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ===========================================================================    =
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ===========================================================================    =

See `config.log' for more details
```

I have tried '`brew install python-dev`' and have run '`brew install python`'. I also have tried the '`./configure LDFLAGS="-L/c/Python27/libs"`', but it won't work...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with python installation. Python on your system is dysfunctional as described here:

[Vim failing to compile with python on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490513/vim-failing-to-compile-with-python-on-os-x)

You have following options:

- Compile sphinxbase without python with configure flag --without-python
- Fix python installation as described in the link above
- Remove brew python and install python from sources/ports/use native python

Answer (score 0):

Running following command worked for me:

`./configure PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS='-u _PyMac_Error /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'`