# Python linking using – LDFLAGS doesn't work

Tags: python, homebrew, pocketsphinx

I'm having the trouble: "Could not link test program to Python."

I have versions 2.7+ installed in `/Library/Frameworks/`.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490513/vim-failing-to-compile-with-python-on-os-x), but because it was posted more than 6 years ago it doesn't consider SIP (System Integrity Protection), which makes it impossible for many users to change `System/Library` files. Additionally, in later versions of Python the `PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR` to `PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR` in Python's make file has been fixed (but the problem persists).

I've tried:

- `./configure PYTHON_LDFLAGS="-l2.7.13_1"`
- `./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/lib"`

…But no combination of LDFLAGS seem to work.

Here's the error:

```
Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ============================================================================
```

And here's the log description:

```
PKG_CONFIG=''
PYTHON='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
PYTHON_CPPFLAGS='-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7'
PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX='${exec_prefix}'
PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS='-u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'
PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS='-ldl  -framework CoreFoundation '
PYTHON_LDFLAGS='-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -lpython2.7'
PYTHON_PLATFORM='darwin'
PYTHON_PREFIX='${prefix}'
PYTHON_SITE_PKG='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
PYTHON_VERSION='2.7'
```

How can I just rip Python out of my system? Is that necessary? Or is there a fix to this error?

Comment: The real error is above the lines you posted, if you want to understand the problem it is better to read the complete log output not just last lines.

Comment: Before those lines were just successful runs. It hit python and stopped. There might be a bit more I can post, but I’m not sure if there’s a log.

Comment: configure log is in a file config.log

Comment: I've added that to my OP.

Comment: You did not add the actual error, it is inside config.log

Comment: That’s all that the other asked of the same question provided. The log doesn’t provide any details about Python, other than these few lines. All of the other lines pertain to the rest of the installation. I can post the whole log if required.

Comment: You should have posted long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same bit of error output on my machine and for me it helped to install `python-dev`, so

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The solution on ubuntu 22.04 was to install python-is-python3:

```
apt install python-is-python3
```